# C: Opening a file at different locations using different file descriptors in multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, file-handling

Say, I have a file with 10 paragraphs. And I have 10 threads that will read these paragraphs independently and feed the data to main thread.

How do I open this file so that my handler is precisely at the location it is supposed to read. Say, I know how many bytes each paragraph is.

I know I can loop over the bytes and get to my desired section but I want a quicker way. Is there any?

Comment: if each thread has its own file descriptor, you can use lseek() in the normal manner. if you are trying to share one file descriptor, you need to deal with races between one thread's lseek() and another's read().

Comment: better - if your OS has it, use pread() or preadv(), which combine lseek() and read/v/(), without changing the file pointer.

Comment: As @Arlie Stephens said, with `lseek()` and presumably all threads are opening the file in `"r"` read mode and not complicating matters by writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

if each thread has its own file descriptor, you can use lseek() in the normal manner. if you are trying to share one file descriptor, you need to deal with races between one thread's lseek() and another's read(). – Arlie Stephens

better - if your OS has it, use pread() or preadv(), which combine lseek() and read/v/(), without changing the file pointer. – Arlie Stephens